# InvalidArgumentError : input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 4 vs 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, image-comparison

I'm a beginner. I tried Image Classification by Tensorflow, and got the following error. I found the similar issue on web, but I couldn't understand. What does the error mean? How should I do for it? Please give me some advice. I use 100 files(png/15pix, 15pix) like a sample image. Tensorflow ver.2.0.0 / python ver.3.8.1 / Jupyter notebook.

[image: sample image]

```
    num_epochs = 30
    steps_per_epoch = round(num_train)//BATCH_SIZE
    val_steps = 20
    history = model.fit(train_data.repeat(),
                epochs=num_epochs,
                steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                validation_data=val_data.repeat(), 
                validation_steps=val_steps)
```

> InvalidArgumentError:  input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 4 vs 3
>        [[node sequential_2/mobilenetv2_1.00_96/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_42611]
>   Function call stack:
>   distributed_function

Comment: We can't tell you what is wrong with the code without seeing the actual code - just the error message is not enough.

Comment: Sorry about that... I uploaded it.

Answer (score 12):

If your model looks like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (150, 150, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
])
```

Change the value of `input_shape` (at the first convolutional layer) from `(150, 150, 3)` to `(150, 150, 4)`.

Replace only the last term (which is 3 here) in the tuple with 4.
That should make it work.

Answer (score 7):

I think you read a 4 channel format image. you should convert input image to 'RGB' before forwarding.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer! In my case, the following program helped it.

```
XXX = tf.convert_to_tensor(XXX[:,:,:3])
```

I wish it would help you too. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error because I was using images that had been converted to grayscale as my data. If anyone is doing this, you can either convert from grayscale to color-format, or re-prepare your data without converting to grayscale, which is what I did.

Per the solution I found:
"Perhaps you are trying to feed a grayscale image into CNN which expects a color image. Find shape of input, e.g. print(model.input.shape) in Keras, you get e.g. (None, 224, 224, 3) and your input blob must have a corresponding shape, so having a grayscale image you have to convert it into a (formal) color image (all the three channels will be same). However, do not forget that you need know also further aspects of the input blob - mean, range, deviation, … having a good shape, it calculates something, but without concerning these aspects, the calculated result is not good"

Comment: kindly post the answer instead of adding a link to it ..

Answer (score 4):

The error is because of mismatch in dimensions of the input provided. The model requires a depth of '3' for the input but is given '4'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having `1 vs 3` error, it is because of input images having `Grayscale` color_mode.

I was using this code:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(f'{dataset}/train', target_size=(150,150),batch_size=32,color_mode='grayscale',class_mode="categorical")
```

To solve the error, I changed the color_mode to `rgb`

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(f'{dataset}/train', target_size=(150,150),batch_size=32,color_mode='rgb',class_mode="categorical")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is the order your dimensions are defined in your Input. If you're getting something like `3 vs 256` in your error message, your images might be getting loaded as `(3, 256, 256)` arrays but your input is expecting `(256, 256, 3)`